# how can I debug custom sink with Python SDK

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a problem with writing custom sink with Python SDK.
To debug it, I used logging.info or print method, but it could not work well.
Are there any good way to debug custom sink?

Comment: Independently run the python code outside of beam & data flow for your expected inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What problems did you have with logging?

When run with the Dataflow pipeline runner, the logs should be accessible in the Cloud Console as described in [Logging Pipeline Messages](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/logging).

You can also use the direct runner to execute the pipeline locally, which may make it easier to debug.